# How to trigger a TAB Key using Javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How to trigger a TAB Key in javafx ?
I have use the given code but, its not working.

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
```

Message shown is : Cannot find symbol variable VK_TAB

Comment: Does it show any errors if you put it in a try catch block?

Comment: @sillyfly : Thankx, it worked.